# Getting rid of an expensive self join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement like this

```
SELECT  
    pa.col1,
    SUM(ps.col2) col2,
    SUM(psl.col2) col2_previous_month
FROM  
    pa
LEFT JOIN 
    ps ON pa.Id = ps.Id AND ps.date = @currDate
LEFT JOIN 
    ps as psl ON psl.Id = ps.Id AND psl.date = dateadd(month, - 1, @currDate)
GROUP BY 
    pa.col1;
```

This SQL is called often and since the table `ps` has 100M rows the left join is hurting. Is there a way to rewrite this using left Join?

Regards
Nick

Comment: What is this query supposed to do? Can you provide some sample data and the required result?

Comment: is indexing the date column in `ps` an option?

Comment: There is an index on the datecolumn but sql server uses a hash join and doesn't use the index

Comment: then try get rid of that dateadd. introduce a second parameter, pass it the previous month.

Comment: Just a thought. I am not sure if get through the nuances trying to answer from phone. If your on 2012+ you could also try the lag and lead functions but inside burry a case expression to choose the previous month then use a similar case in the order by. That way you only have to join only once and window function may preform well not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
    Select pa.col1
          ,col2      =isnull(sum(case when ps.date=@currDate                   then ps.col2 else null end),0)
          ,col2_prior=isnull(sum(case when ps.date=dateadd(month,-1,@currDate) then ps.col2 else null end),0)
     From pa
     JOIN ps as ps ON pa.Id  = ps.Id 
      and ps.date in (@currDate,dateadd(month,-1,@currDate))
     Group By pa.col1
```

Comment: I thought to that as well. But you forgot the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

If the query of John doesn't help you can also try this one:

```
SELECT  
    pa.col1
    ,SUM(ps1.col2) col2
    ,SUM(ps2.col2) col2_previous_month

FROM  pa

    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT col2
            FROM ps
            WHERE date = @currDate
        ) ps1 ON ON pa.Id = ps1.Id        

     LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT col2
            FROM ps
            WHERE date = dateadd(month, - 1, @currDate)
        ) ps2 ON ON pa.Id = ps2.Id

GROUP BY pa.col1;
```

I thought to it after having read your comments.

It is exactly the same as your initial query except that I moved the search on dates inside a nested query, which might help the optimizer to properly use the index.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks fine. In order to have it perform fast, you should have the following indexes:

- pa (id)
- ps (id, date)

If you want it still faster, use covering indexes:

- pa (id, col1)
- ps (id, date, col2)